# I want to convert a specific string to json

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsstring

server response 
-> NSString : { key1 = value1 }{ key2 = value2 }{ key3 = value3 }

How do I convert it to json?

What should I do?

Comment: did it help in any way?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is something like this , but im not suer if you can use `=` isntead of `:`

```
  NSString *stringValue =@"[{ \"Key1\":\"Value1\" },{ \"Key2\":\"Value2\" },{ \"Key3\":\"Value3\" }]";
NSLog(@"StringValues from Server=%@", stringValue);

// Convert to JSON object:
NSArray *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[stringValue dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                      options:0 error:NULL];
NSLog(@"jsonObject=%@", jsonObject);
```

If this is not what you want try to give us some code and explain how you want it done